# iOS XCTestCase to launch, perform some actions, kill the app and re-launch app

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase

I have to automate following scenario using swift and XCTestCase on iOS simulator.

- Step1: Launch the app
- Step2: Performa some actions on the app
- Step3: Kill the app
- Step4: Re-launch the app and check if the actions performed are persistent

I found in one of our questions to use the below snippet.

```
    XCUIDevice.shared().press(XCUIDeviceButton.home)
    sleep(60)
    XCUIDevice.shared().siriService.activate(voiceRecognitionText: "Open {appName}")
```

It did not work for me, can some one please suggest any different approach.

thanks,

Comment: You are doing unit tests, right? If so, can you switch over to Xcode *UI tests* for this specific test?

Answer (score 3):

To launch or re-launch use `launch`:

```swift
XCUIApplication().launch()
```

To terminate application use `terminate()`. But according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500467-launch):

> If the application is already running, this call will terminate the existing instance, to ensure a clean launch state for the newly launched instance.

Shortly. Your test could look like:

```swift
XCUIApplication().launch()
// some actions
XCUIApplication().launch()
// some action
```

Comment: Nice answer! But I believe this would only work if he is using UI tests (and not unit tests), right?

Comment: Yes. This will only work with UI test. I doubt it could be done with unit tests.